# Google Maps direction results not changing after adress change

Tags: geolocation, google-maps-api-3

i mix geolocation and a form input for a route planner.
After changing the adress in the form or using geolocation the map works great.
But the directions in the directionsDisplay.setPanel are not changing :-(

Heres my code:

http://pastie.org/2001742

EDIT:
i just realised that i get the new directions. But the old directions are not deleted. They show up one below the other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to the previous DirectionsRenderer and call .setMap(null) when you want to disabled it.

Comment: ah OK. directionsDisplay.setPanel(null) did it. Thanks @Ryan